# java FileNotFoundException Too many open files

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, copy

I'm trying to build an automatic backup script in Java. I'm not very good at Java though so this is proving difficult.

Here's my code:

```
package javatest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {   
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String path = "/mnt/192.168.1.89";
      String destFile = "/home/scott/backup.zip";

      zip(path,destFile);
 }

 private static void zip(String src, String destFile) throws Exception
 {
     FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
     ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);

     addFolderToZip("", src, zip);

     zip.flush();
     zip.close();
 }

 private static void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder, ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception
 {
       File folder = new File(srcFolder);

       for (String filename : folder.list())
       {
            if (path.equals("")) {
                 addFileToZip(folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + filename, zip);
            } else {
                 addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + filename, zip);
            }
       }
 }

 private static void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile, ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception
 {
     File folder = new File(srcFile);

     if (folder.isDirectory()) {
          addFolderToZip(path,srcFile,zip);
     } else {
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

          int len;

          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

          zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));

          while((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
          {
               zip.write(buf,0,len);
          }
     }
 }
}
```

And here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: FILENAME (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:53)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:37)
    at javatest.Main.addFileToZip(Main.java:47)
    at javatest.Main.addFolderToZip(Main.java:35)
    at javatest.Main.zip(Main.java:22)
    at javatest.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: "automatic backup script"  Have you considered using Ant for this?  Is this script for your use, or for an intranet, or 'end users at home'?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `close()` both your:

- `ZipOutputStream` (which you rightly did so), and
- `FileInputStream`

Right now, there's many open connections in your streams.

in `addFolderToZip()` method, close your `FileInputStream` at the end like so:

```
try {
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Log exception
}
```

Comment: `ZipOutputStream` is being closed.

Comment: @mre, yes, but not the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: by closing the `ZipOutputStream`, you implicitly close the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

close those streams best practice is to do it in try-finally blocks like so (finally blocks are nearly always executed when the try block exits

```
private static void zip(String src, String destFile) throws Exception
 {
   FileOutputStream fileWriter=null;
   ZipOutputStream zip = null;
   try{
     fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destFile)
     zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);

     addFolderToZip("", src, zip);

     zip.flush();
   }finally{
     if(zip!=null)zip.close();//close also does a flush
     if(fileWriter!=null)fileWriter.close();
   }
 }

private static void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile, ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception
 {
     File folder = new File(srcFile);

     if (folder.isDirectory()) {
          addFolderToZip(path,srcFile,zip);
     } else {
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

          int len;

          FileInputStream in = null;
          try{
              in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
              zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));

              while((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
              {
                   zip.write(buf,0,len);
              }
          }finally{if(in!=null)in.close()}//<<--ensure in is closed you forgot this in the example code
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
while((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
{
    zip.write(buf,0,len);
}
in.close(); //You have to close file !
```

You have to close file when you don't need it anymore

Answer (score 0):

In `addFileToZip`, just do `in.close()` at the end of the else, it should do the trick.
Of course, proper code would also check Exceptions in order to close streams even in case of problem.